# Deleting a Node in a Doubly Linked List at a specfic index in java

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I have created a doubly linked list, that appends new nodes to the doubly linked list. I am currently trying to work on deleting a node at a specific index.
This is my node class, which initializes three variables, next, previous, and it imports objects from a student class that I have. Shouldn't the `for` loop iterate up to the value of the index entered and then redirect the next value?

`Node` Class:

```java
public class Node {
    Student student;
    Node next;
    Node previous;

    public Node(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return student.toString();
    }
}
```

---

`DoublyLinkedList` Class:

```java
public class DoublyLinkedList <T extends Comparable<T>> {
    protected Node head;
    protected Node tail;
    int size=0;

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    public Node append(Student student) {
        Node append = new Node(student);
        if (head == null) {
            head = append;
            tail = append;
        }
        else {
            append.previous = tail;
            tail.next = append;
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        size++;
        return append;
    }

    public void delete(int location) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Node current = head;
        int counter = 1;
        int i;
        // Exception error for cases in which there are no nodes
        if (head == null || location < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry but the DLL is NULL, please add nodes");
        // Cases in which the person wants to delete the head at index 0
        if (location == 0) {
            /* If the node that is next is not null we make that the head
             */
            if (head.next != null) {
                head.next.previous = head;
            }
        }
        for (i = 1; head != null && i < location; i++) {
            head = head.next;
        }
        if (head == null)
            head = head.next.previous;
    }
}
```

I believe the cases that I made for situations where the head is null, a negative value is entered, and the head node is being deleted are correct. I believe the problem is iterating up the given parameter (index of node being deleted). I did a `for` loop that iterates up to the given index. What I was trying to do is once the value of head reaches the parameter entered, it would redirect the next of the `Node` it iterated up to. Is this logic correct and the syntax wrong or is there another logic for a case like this?

Comment: Rather than repeatedly checking for `head!=null`, consider checking once at entry for the case of trying to delete from an empty list and then proceeding to following links to see if the indexed element actually exists.

Comment: Also, if your application (assignment?) allows it, you might keep a count of the entries in the list so that you can (a) tell without link-chasing whether the link exists, and (b) decide whether an indexed node is nearer the front or or the back.

Comment: I posted an answer with general remarks regarding your code. For the future, try to ask a specific question, and not a broad one. Like "I input `a` and expect `b`, but got `c`." Also if this is homework, say it : it won't help you to have just the code, you won't learn anything

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be homework, so I won't give a full code, but pointers to where mistakes are. If this isn't the case feel free to comment and I'll remove this. This should be a comment, but this is too long to fit in the comment section.

There are four things that seem off in the `delete` method:

#### When iterating over the array to find the node to delete, the head is modified.

```java
for (i = 1; head != null && i < location; i++) {
     head = head.next;
}
```

This will permanently modify the head of the doubled linked list, meaning that the nodes before the new head are lost.
You should use a variable to iterate (I believe `current` was supposed to be that ?)

#### When you delete the head

It's correct that there is additional work to do when the location to delete is the head, but `head.next.previous = head;` does nothing : `head` is already the previous node of `head.next`.

#### When you delete the tail

There is additional work to do when you delete the head, but also when you delete the tail.

#### You never actually remove anything

Other than the lost nodes when iteration, you never remove any node form the list.

I suggest you start with simple case and see what your current implementation does, then try to correct it. You can also do it pen and paper by drawing the double linked list, this could help you build an intuition on what steps should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DoublyLinkedList` class is generic. Therefore class `Node` should also be generic. Consequently, class `Student` needs to implement interface `Comparable`.

Since you have a doubly-linked list, method `delete` also needs to update `tail` in class `DoublyLinkedList`.

Since class `DoublyLinkedList` has member `size`, method `delete` also needs to update that member as well.

Because class `DoublyLinkedList` has member `size`, the parameter, `location`, of method `delete` is valid if it is not negative and also if it is less than `size`.

There are three, separate cases that method `delete` needs to handle:

1. You are deleting the first `Node` in `DoublyLinkedList`.

   - You also need to handle the case where there is only one `Node` in `DoublyLinkedList`.
2. You are deleting the last `Node` in `DoublyLinkedList`.
3. You are deleting a `Node` which is neither the first nor the last.

   - You also need to handle the case where you are deleting the second last `Node`.

You didn't post code for class `Student` so I just made up a class.

In the below code, I added `toString` method in class `DoublyLinkedList` simply in order to help "visualize" the list.

I also added a `main` method to class `DoublyLinkedList` to demonstrate use of method `delete`.

```java
public class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    protected Node<T> head;
    protected Node<T> tail;
    int size = 0;

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    public Node<T> append(T student) {
        Node<T> append = new Node<>(student);
        if (head == null) {
            head = append;
            tail = append;
        }
        else {
            append.previous = tail;
            tail.next = append;
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        size++;
        return append;
    }

    public void delete(int location) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Exception error for cases in which there are no nodes
        if (head == null || location < 0 || location >= size)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry but the DLL is NULL, please add nodes");
        // Cases in which the person wants to delete the head at index 0
        if (location == 0) {
            head = head.next;
            if (head != null) {
                head.previous = null;
            }
            if (size == 2) {
                tail = head;
            }
        }
        else if (location == size - 1) {
            tail = tail.previous;
            tail.next = null;
        }
        else {
            Node<T> current = head;
            for (int i = 1; i < location; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = current.next.next;
            if (current.next == null) {
                tail = current;
            }
            else {
                current.next.previous = current;
            }
        }
        size--;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(String.format("[%d]:", size));
        Node<T> current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            sb.append(current);
            sb.append('\u2192');
            current = current.next;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublyLinkedList<Student> dll = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
        System.out.println(dll);
        dll.append(new Student());
        System.out.println(dll);
        dll.append(new Student());
        System.out.println(dll);
        dll.append(new Student());
        System.out.println(dll);
        dll.append(new Student());
        System.out.println(dll);
        dll.delete(1);
        System.out.println(dll);
    }
}

class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private static int counter;
    private int id;

    public Student() {
        id = ++counter;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return id - o.id;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equal = this == obj;
        if (!equal) {
            if (obj instanceof Student) {
                Student other = (Student) obj;
                equal = id == other.id;
            }
        }
        return equal;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d", id);
    }
}

class Node<T> {
    T student;
    Node<T> next;
    Node<T> previous;

    public Node(T student) {
        this.student = student;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return student.toString();
    }
}
```